# ajax doesn't work with the array

Tags: javascript, ajax

i'm trying to load information from my text file to an array using ajax and i'm using this code :

```
function loadWords(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "dico/francais.html");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE && xhr.status == 200){
            dico = xhr.responseText.split("\n");
            for(var i=0; i<wordsNBR; i++){
                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*dico.length);
                words[i] = dico[x];
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

it wordks but when i try to change

```
for(var i=0; i<wordsNBR; i++){
                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*dico.length);
                words[i] = dico[x];
            }
```

to

```
for(var i=0; i<wordsNBR; i++){
                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*dico.length);
                words.push(dico.splice(x,1));
            }
```

it doesn't work any body know why ?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an error message? Or does it do something other than what you expected?

Comment: sorry it's dico and not table it's a mistake

Comment: i dont get it why people still avoid using ajax libraries.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky I use jQuery for many things but it doesn't make ajax simpler when you have raw text or not totally normalized json. using vanilla js for that is fine.

Comment: true, true, true but only if its correctly implemented. this code above would not run in all browsers and you know that too. that IS what libs are for.

Comment: this is the error that i get "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]"

Answer (score 1):

`dico.splice(x,1)` changes the array and returns the removed element. This might make sense with `x` < `dico.length` as it takes a word at random in the dico array.

So I suppose your first error is just that you're using the wrong variable.

Another error is that [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array and not just an element. If you want the returned element, you need to take `dico.splice(x,1)[0]`.

Do this :

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*dico.length); // takes an index in what is left in dico
words.push(dico.splice(x,1)[0]); // removes the word and add it to words
```

Comment: no i have wrote a wrong code and i have fixed it so now you can help me to find the real probleme. thank you

Comment: I found another bug. See edit.